# Is registration required for custom SCIM extensions?

Tags: ldap, scim, scim2

In our product, we have decided to provide a custom schema extension which will have the attributes that are neither part of core schema nor enterprise schema provided by SCIM2.0. Do we need to register this schema extension with IANA?
If yes, what is the procedure and if no, is the extension URI just a unique identifier and local to the service provider?

In https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643#section-10.3, it is given that

> Registration of new schemas or modifications under the namespaces
> "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core" and "urn:ietf:params:scim:api"
> should be reviewed by a designated expert, whereas schemas outside
> these above namespaces may be registered with a simple review (e.g.,
> check for spam) by the designated expert on a first-come-first-served
> basis.

In the IANA SCIM registry: https://www.iana.org/assignments/scim/scim.xhtml, there are no schema extensions registered by any Identity Providers. Does that mean custom schema extensions need not be registered and just need to be maintained by the service provider itself?